# web scraping articles get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all article's title, link, date from `atlasobscura.com`.

At the beginning I've written the code in requests + parsel + xpath.
(Result has no errors)

But this time I'm re-writing the code by using BeautifulSoup and I've got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:\Python\Atlasobscura.com_2.py", line 21, in 
> href = 'https://www.atlasobscura.com' + str(s.find('div').find('a')['href'].text)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

If anyone can fix this problem.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

title = []
link = []
date = []

for x in range(1, 662):
    print(f'=====> Scraping from page {x}')
    url = f'https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles?page={x}'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    
    articles = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12')
    for s in articles:
        story = s.find('div', class_='content-card-text').find('h3').find('span').text
        title.append(story)
        href = 'https://www.atlasobscura.com' + str(s.find('div').find('a')['href'].text)
        link.append(href)
        m_d_y = s.find('div', class_='detail-sm article-card-detail article-card-date').text.strip()
        date.append(m_d_y)
        print(story, href, m_d_y)

    atlasobscura = pd.DataFrame({
        'Title': title,
        'Link': link,
        'Date': date
    })
    atlasobscura.to_excel('Atlasobscura.com.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: What code line gives this error?

Comment: Why are you adding `.text` to the end of every `find()`? `.find('a')['href']` already returns a string

Comment: @Prophet I've just edited info. It's line 21.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I'm not good at Python, and the original code was written in requests +  parsel + xpath. Now I'm wrting again in BeautifulSoup, which quite make me confused.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I just removed all .text from the code. Now I'm getting new error (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Traceback the problem is here

```py
str(s.find('div').find('a')['href'].text)
```

`s` is a web element. applying `find()` on it gives another web element
So after applying

```py
s.find('div').find('a')
```

we have some web element.
Now we apply `['href']` on it, this gives the `href` attribute value of that web element.
So

```py
s.find('div').find('a')['href']
```

returns some string.
We can not apply `.text` method on a string.
This is what the error says.
So, you should simply remove `.text` there, leave it as:

```py
href = 'https://www.atlasobscura.com' + str(s.find('div').find('a')['href'])
```

`.text` method can be applied on a web element object to get it's text value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried to remove .text from the code. Now I've get (line 23, in <module>
    m_d_y = s.find('div', class_='detail-sm article-card-detail article-card-date').strip()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable)

Comment: Well, not this means that at some step this does not give you a web element. You have to debug. First of all verify if `articles` is a list of web elements, not an empty list.

Comment: If `articles` is an empty list your locator is wrong or maybe `soup` is already empty. 
In case `articles` is non-empty validate if for each element there you can apply `s.find('div').find('a')` and each such `a` element has `href` value.

Comment: OK, this kind of empty list problem has been making lots of problems, and I'm tired of self learning. All I'm doing this s**t is after I successfully wrote first code in XPath, I'm trying to add multiprocessing module in it. But those examples on internet, many of them are wrote in BeautifulSoup. That's why I'm struggling.

Comment: Thanks Prophet. To be honest I can only understand 50% of your comment. Anyway now I know I hate this list.

Comment: Well, actually I never used BeautifulSoup. Only Selenium.

Comment: What is unclear? Can you debug and see on what step you getting empty list or NoneType object i.e getting nothing?

Comment: I've been thinking of using Selenium too. But it's slower than I thought, even if I use headless mode.

Comment: I understand. If so you have to learn and practice the s**t named BS :)

Comment: Uncleared parts are english and python basic. Both I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Again, you can ask to clarify anything that is unclear. For me English is not mother tongue  too. Even not my second language :)

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks for your kind help. I'm having hard time like everyone else in the world. I've lost energy after I felt like I couldn't write something useful in simple code.

Comment: It's Ok. Just practice until you will do this easy and perfectly :)

Comment: Thanks again Prophet. I'll try as much as possible, but first of all I really want to hang out with people normally like few years before. I wish you be safe and get better.